# what are the weights for in predict function in R

Tags: r, glmnet

I got the Coefficient of the min $\lambda$ value from the `cv.glmnet` function. Now I would like to predict the values using the `predict()` function. I see that it takes weights as an argument. Do the weights imply the coefficients of the model?

I would like to know how to use the coefficient values to predict the output of a test set data. Do we have any function that takes the coefficient values as inputs?

Answer (score 4):

The `predict` function does not take a `weights` argument, but `cv.glmnet` does. However, the `weights` argument is optional and refers to the weights you wish to assign to your observations. For instance, if you had 20 observations and wished to give the ten most recent observations double the weight of the first ten, you could do:

```
weights = c(rep(1, 10), rep(2, 10))  
cvfit = cv.glmnet(x, y, weights, ...)
```

You need not worry about the sum of the weights you specify as these are scaled automatically.
You could then pass your `cv.glmnet` object directly to the predict function:

```
predict(cvfit, newx, s = "lambda.min")
```

Comment: I would like to know how to use the coefficient values to predict the output of a test set data. Do we have any function that takes the coefficient values as inputs?

Comment: You can do just that using the predict function. The predict function takes your fitted model (or, in your case, you fitted cv.glmnet object) as its first parameter. The second parameter will then be your newx object, i.e., your test data. There is no need for a function that takes the coefficients directly, as these are painlessly extracted from your fitted model object. But perhaps I am missing something: is there a specific reason why you would wish to circumvent the predict function?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, and this could be more a question as well, that for the prediction part, the newx will also need to be weighted. If instead of predict, glmnet can be used as well where weights can be passed for the fixed s being lambda.min.

Can someone respond whether this would be the correct approach? Does predict function automatically incorporate the weights which were passed into cvfit?

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Please don't post tentative answers and ask for 
feedback.  [stats.SE] is strictly a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  If you want
to ask about your understanding of something, please post it as a new question.  
Since you're new here, you may want to take our [tour], which has information for 
new users.